# Yowza restored status bar too many times

Tags: swift

As I call function OpenGC then the leaderboard appears fine, but when I close the Game Center everything is fine, but then I get the following errors in debug:

> 2018-04-03 01:12:10.143194+0300 app.name[356:38176] [Error] yowza! restored status bar too many times!
>   2018-04-03 01:12:10.161688+0300 app.name[356:38176] [Error] Extension request cancelled with error: Error Domain=NSExtensionErrorDomain Code=-2 "Extension cancelled by host." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Extension cancelled by host.}

The code i am using is here:

```
@IBAction func OpenGC(_ sender: Any) {
    let VC = self
    let GCVC = GKGameCenterViewController()
    GCVC.gameCenterDelegate = self
    GCVC.viewState = .leaderboards
    GCVC.leaderboardIdentifier = "my.leaderboard"
    VC.present(GCVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
    gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have found same issue but no solution in:
[Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-11-game-center-overlay-warning-yowza.496367/)

Really appreciate if anyone has ideas!

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something actually descriptive. If you remove *Game Center* (which is available in the tags and therefore uselessly redundant in the title) it leaves *IOS error*, which is totally meaningless. Your title should describe the problem or question in a way that conveys meaning, and that will be helpful to a future reader here seeing it in a list of search results. Thanks.

Comment: Any new info re this? I'm testing a leaderboard and am getting the same error.

Comment: Error remained, but app review by Apple was positive!

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered this error as well on our tvOS build (iOS is working fine) using Xcode 10.2.1. Upon further investigation done by a colleague, seems that other tvOS games found on the tvOS AppStore are experiencing the same behavior.

I've filed a bug with Apple, but at the time of writing it seems that nobody managed to fix this so you're better off just submiting it like this until Apple provides a fix for this issue.